# How to define a list of matrix (array) in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, list, rcpp

I am trying to make big object in c++, using Rcpp lib, which is a matrix of negative and positive numbers, I define an auxiliary bidimensional array of type double because i couldnt use NumericMatrix due to the dimensions of the object.
Now I am trying to put this giant arrays into a std::list, such as:

```
std::list<NumericMatrix> listOfMatrix;
```

But with arrays:

```
std::list<double array[nrows][ncols]> listOfMarix;
```

Comment: Sorry for the wrong code comments, I'm pretty new at this '-.-

Comment: What's your question? Is what you're trying not working?

Comment: this code is wrong, i want to do a list of bidimensional arrays, and i dont know how

Comment: Use a nested `std::array` or `std::vector`. Do you seriously need to use `std::list` anyway? It should be your last choice of a structure.

Comment: well i could try to do a bigger array using a kind of cbind() in c++

Comment: But i dont know if i can do this with an object that is not a Rcpp object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `Rcpp::List` for the return.

Here is a really simple example with two matrices; you can also use multi-dimensional arrays but it is less common.  Also see RcppArmadillo for vector, matrix, cube and field types.

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> cppFunction("Rcpp::List foo() { return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::NumericMatrix(2,2), Rcpp::NumericMatrix(3,3)); }")
R> foo()
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0

R>
```

In R, everything is just a contiguous vector. Matrices happen to have a (size 2) dimension attributed; you can generalize this to three and more dimensions -- but such data structures are rare in R, and there are few converters.

Here is a minimal example of a 2x2x2 array:

```
R> cppFunction('Rcpp::NumericVector bar() { Rcpp::NumericVector x(8); Rcpp::IntegerVector d = Rcpp::IntegerVector::create(2,2,2); x.attr("dim") = d; return(x); }')
R> bar()
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0

R>
```

You can combine several of these in a list the same way as I did above.